# Extract time from string in format %I:%M %p

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string '10:26 PM - words are here' and would like the following extracted

```
10:26 PM
```

Sometimes the string is also in the format of '09:26 AM words are here' where the dash is no longer present. I had the following code

```
re.split(r'[-](?=[ ])', regex_str)[0]
```

But once the dash is no longer present it breaks.

Bare in mind the time can also be 9:26PM and doesn't have to be 09:26PM

Comment: Try matching that string: [`re.search(r'^\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M\b', s)`](https://ideone.com/jfV4b6). Is that string always at the string start?

Comment: If you just need the first two non-whitespace chunks, why not use `" ".join(s.split(" ", 2)[:2])`?

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, only saw your comment once my answer was posted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The time is not necessarily always at the start

Comment: Then use `re.search(r'\b\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M\b', s)`

Comment: @Kalimantan Please add all information to the open post next time. We only know what you tell us.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Sorry about that. I hadn't noticed that edge case

Comment: Not a problem, you can use Daniel's solution which works well. As a sanity check you could add word boundaries as Wiktor suggests in his comment above.

Comment: can try this too: `gsub('[^0-9APM:]', '', '9:26 AM words are here' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the matches in the text like this:

```
for match in re.finditer('[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\\s*(AM|PM)', text):
    print match.group()
```

For `'10:26 PM - words are here 9:45 AM'` the **output** is:

```
10:26 PM
9:45 AM
```